# Relations between classes entityframeworkcore code-first

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I am a beginner in entity framework core but I have used Linq to SQL before by creating the database first.
I am trying to write the code first with entity.

I have a database with multiple tables, and cannot figure out why i cannot use the relationships between classes.

Simple Case: 
I have a Class Chat that relates with a many to many relationship with the class User.

Chat class

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int StarterUserId { get; set; }
public User StarterUser { get; set; }
public int OtherUserId { get; set; }
public User OtherUser { get; set; }
```

User class has an Id property.

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public List<Chat> InChats { get; set; }
public List<Chat> OutChats { get; set; }
```

And I have defined in the OnModelCreating method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Chat>()
            .HasOne(x => x.StarterUser)
            .WithMany(m => m.OutChats)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.StarterUserId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Chat>()
            .HasOne(x => x.OtherUser)
            .WithMany(m => m.InChats)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.OtherUserId);
```

When I get a Chat object, and watch it properties, I have
`OtherUser` as an object of `User` class, and `OtherUserId=26` (GOOD)

But i have `StarterUserId=1` and I have `StarterUser as null`.

In the database I can see the relationships that are defined correctly.
`StarterUserId` and `OtherUserId` are both foreign keys in `Users` Table

Why is that? How can I fix this?

**Solved:** I enabled lazy loading and not i can get the related data.

1. I installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies` package from nuget
2. When adding my `DbContext`I enabled lazy loading using `.UseLazyLoadingProxies()`
3. Changed the modifiers from `public` to `public virtual` for the properties i needed to get the related data

Comment: Problem is in your query but you did not add the query to the question, Rather you have added a lot of other code! Please add your query to the question.

Comment: i am just inspecting the  Chat object in Visual studio. No query

Comment: Check my answer please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your query but you did not add your query to the question!!. I assume you are missing `eager-loading` the related entities.

So you have to eager load the `OtherUser` using `.Inlcude` in your query and your query should be as follows:

```
_dbContext.Chats.Include(c => c.StarterUser)
                .Include(c => c.OtherUser).Where(c => c.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

For more details: [Loading Related Data in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)